# socat as SCTP client

Tags: socat

There is an SCTP (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol ) server running in my network. I want to send it a simple message  to verify that it works and is accessible. How can I do it with socat?
I could read "man socat", but it doesn't have examples for SCTP.

Comment: Have you looked at `man socat`, and in particular the options for SCTP?

Comment: `socat -x -d -d -d - sctp:host:port` and type the messages you want to  send.